# Delay a http-request without javascript

Tags: html, css, http-request, delayed-execution

world!

I would like to ask if there is a way to delay forwarding to another page on a control click without javscript?
I am working on a webapp that shall work with and without JS. For the non-JS version, I would like an animation (e.g. 'index-out') to run and finish before loading the new page.
I actually cannot imagine there is a way as the HTTP-Request will be sent instantly after the button click, and CSS and HTML are not able to interfere with this functionality, however, maybe you guys can make me smarter today ;)

My alternative solution may be to add the animation on the second page (e.g. 'index-out' followed by 'another-page-in') but this way the animation is played always, even when I directly head to .../another-page.html. If I find a workaround, I will let you know. I guess, however, that I may have to set page-transitions/animations aside.

So long - happy condin'.

Comment: Redirect to your own PHP page with a `meta` delay and redirect onwards?

Comment: I am on rails but I will consider it. Thank you